# How can I speed up replacing bytes in a data file

Tags: swift

I am currently using the following function to replace bytes in a data file but it is proving to be pretty slow.

Any ideas on how I can speed this up.

I need to read the original data file, replace every occurrence of a specific string with a replacement string (same number of characters), and write the modified data to a new subfolder using the original file name.

EDIT:

- replacement strings are 4 or 5 characters
- data file is 25MB

It seems that searching through the file is taking a long time - 10 seconds after the first 4 occurrences are replaced. First 4 done in fractions of a second.

I know there are 4 occurrences of the string that need replacement and if I break out after the 4th replacement then it is very fast.  However it is not impossible that there might be more occurences so this is a risky 'optimisation' lol!

```
public func edit(from: String, to: String, url: URL) -> Bool
{

    do
    {
        var bytes = [UInt8]()

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.url)

        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.count)
        data.copyBytes(to: &buffer, count: data.count)
        bytes = buffer
        
        var stringBytes = Array(from.utf8)

        var replaceBytes = Array(to.utf8)

        replaceAll(source: bytes, oldBytes: stringBytes, newBytes: replaceBytes)

        let newData = Data(bytes: &bytes, count: bytes.count)
        
        try newData.write(to: url)

        return true
        
    } catch
    {
        return false
    }
    
}
private func replaceAll(source: [UInt8], oldBytes: [UInt8], newBytes: [UInt8]) -> Void
{
    var source = source
    
    for i in 0..<(source.count - oldBytes.count + 1)
    {
        var match = true
        
        for j in 0..<oldBytes.count
        {
            if (source[i + j] != oldBytes[j])
            {
                match = false
                break
            }
        }
        if (match)
        {
            for j in 0..<newBytes.count
            {
                source[i+j] = newBytes[j]
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for one you could set `i += newBytes.count` after you do the replacement.

You should also set some local variables for the data lengths. I'm not sure if Swift needs to traverse the data each time you request the length but it can't hurt to store those in variables.

Comment: Actually that makes no difference.  A python script doing essentially the same thing is hundreds of times faster.

Comment: Please give more details. What is the size of the file and how long does your code take? What string did you replace with what string? Did you compile with optimisations?

Comment: Use a Stream Reader instead of the full file size, and iterates on it maybe? That would reduce the memory, but not necessarily the speed. Also, why use Byte? You could use `Data` which has a `replacing()` (`replacing(_:with:maxReplacements:)`) method, since it's `RangeReplaceableCollection` compliant and you might currently loose speed with Data to Array conversions (but it's iOS16+/macOS13+)

Comment: Side note, the `replacing(_:with:maxReplacements:)` (or the `replace()` version which is mutating) is also on Array, so `replaceAll(source: bytes, oldBytes: stringBytes, newBytes: replaceBytes)` could be `source.replace(stringBytes, with: replaceBytes)`.

Comment: @Larme - thanks will test those options.